# writing text below a word in mathrm in mathmode

Tags: math-mode

I would like that the part `{0 \neq w \in \mathcal{H}_{k-t}}` appear strictly below `sup` in the following

`\[
\mathrm{ sup }_{0 \neq w \in \mathcal{H}_{k-t}}
\]`

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel predefines a `\sup` command that does what you want:

```
\[
\sup_{0 \neq w \in \mathcal{H}_{k-t}}
\]
```

The predefined math operators with the same property are

```
\max \min \sup \min \det \Pr \gcd
```

as well as all those in the "lim" family

```
\lim \limsup \liminf
```

Notice that the subscript will be placed below the operator name only in display math, for good typographical reasons.

With the help of the `amsmath` package (only `amsopn` would really be needed) it's easy to define new ones:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\blurb}{blurb}
```

will make `\blurb` behave like `\sup`.